Kentico 13 Handle Reset button state on a custom form control
I built some custom filtering controls for a specific page type and I created an alternative form to include the custom controls. The filtering works perfectly fine. The only issue I have is the 'Reset' button does not reset the controls. How do I handle the reset on each custom control?

All the custom controls have a similar implementation. Below is the code for one of the custom filtering controls.
public partial class CMSModules_Custom_Filters_PageTagsFilter :  FormEngineUserControl
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value selected within the filter.
    /// </summary>
    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return chkPageTags.GetSelectedItems();
        }
        set
        {
            //chklFeedTypes.SelectedValue = ValidationHelper.GetString(value, "");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the SQL Where condition used to limit the data displayed in the connected UniGrid.
    /// </summary>
    public override string GetWhereCondition()
    {
        string whereQuery = string.Empty;

        if (Value != null)
        {
            var allValues = (IEnumerable<ListItem>)Value;

            List<ListItem> items = allValues.ToList();

            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                whereQuery = "(";
                for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (whereQuery != "(")
                    {
                        whereQuery += " OR ";
                    }

                    // Add a condition for each value
                    whereQuery += "EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM STRING_SPLIT(PageTags, ';') WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(value)) = N'" + items[i].Value + "')";
                }

                whereQuery += ")";
            }
        }

        return whereQuery;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the filtering options during the initialization of the control.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        ITagGroupInfoProvider tagGroupProvider = new TagGroupInfoProvider();
        var tagGroup = tagGroupProvider.Get().Where(o => o.TagGroupName == "ContentHub").FirstOrDefault();

        if(tagGroup != null)
        {
            int groupId = tagGroup.TagGroupID;


            ITagInfoProvider provider = new TagInfoProvider();
            var tags = provider.Get().Where(o=>o.TagGroupID == groupId);

            var allTags = tags;

            chkPageTags.DataSource = allTags;
            chkPageTags.DataBind();
        }

       

    }


}


<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  Codebehind="PageTagsFilter.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="CMSModules_Custom_Filters_PageTagsFilter" %>

<%@ Register namespace="CMS.Base.Web.UI" assembly="CMS.Base.Web.UI" tagPrefix="cms" %>

<div style="max-height:200px;max-width:300px;overflow-y: scroll;">
<cms:CMSCheckBoxList ID="chkPageTags" runat="server" DataValueField="TagID" DataTextField="TagName">
</cms:CMSCheckBoxList>
</div>


When you say RESET, do you mean reset it to the previously saved values or clear everything from the form?

@BrendenKehren Clear everything from the form
